# How to perform a VLOOKUP in R?

Tags: merge, dplyr, match, vlookup

I am replicating a CSV file in R (originally created in excel), that is compiled using various data sources. When i made this CSV in excel i used a vlookup to populate certain columns based on another data source/other spreadsheet.

How can i populate a column in R using something similar to a VLOOKUP? i.e. looking for a variable in an external source and matching it with another column in the df?

For example, the formula in the excel version is = 
=VLOOKUP('[Spreadsheet1]Tab1'!A22,'[Spreadsheet2]Tab2'!$A$6:$B$500,2,FALSE)

How can i make this same formula in R code?

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::left_join()` should do the trick:

```
myData <- data.frame(
  x = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c')
)

lookUpData <- data.frame(
  key = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  value = c(1, 2, 3)
)

library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  left_join(lookUpData, by = c(x = 'key')) %>%
  rename(newCol = value)


  x newCol
1 a      1
2 b      2
3 b      2
4 c      3
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i shall try this. Although i've experimented a lot with dplyr/joins/merges and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not trying to add a column, instead I am trying to populate an existing column with external data. Does this make any difference to your suggestion?

Comment: No, the process should be the same. Is your existing column populated entirely with null values?

Comment: Okay thanks! Yes, there are blank cells. No data at all.

Comment: Great. If this answers your question please green checkmark it so others can find the canonical answer.